# Search for pattern in datatable with grepl

Tags: r, data.table, grepl

I have a datatable, which looks like this:

```
test <- data.table(
        ID = 1:5,
        pattern = c("01234567 ~ 01234567 ~ 12345678 ~ 23456789 ~ A012345",
                    "A012345 ~ 12345678 ~ A01234 ~ 12345678 ~ 23456789 ~ A012345",
                    "A012345 ~ 12345678 ~ 01234567 ~ 12345678 ~ 23456789",
                    "12345678 ~ 01234567 ~ 12345678 ~ 23456789",
                    "A0123456 ~ 12345678 ~ 01234567 ~ 12345678 ~ 23456789")
        )
```

I want to know if the rows have a pattern, starting with a character (A-Z) and have less than 7 or more than 7 digits. For this, I want to add two new columns, named `smaller7` and `greater7`, which say TRUE or FALSE.

I tried with this:

```
      # less than 7 digits
      test[, smaller7 := grepl("(^| )[A-Z].{1,5}($| )", test$pattern, ignore.case = TRUE)]
      
      # more than 7 digits
      test[, greater7 := grepl("(^| )[A-Z].{7,}($| )$", test$pattern, ignore.case = TRUE)]
```

The result is:

| ID | pattern | smaller7 | greater7 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 01234567 ~ 01234567 ~ 12345678 ~ 23456789 ~ A012345 | FALSE | FALSE |
| 2 | A012345 ~ 12345678 ~ A01234 ~ 12345678 ~ 23456789 ~ A012345 | TRUE | TRUE |
| 3 | A012345 ~ 12345678 ~ 01234567 ~ 12345678 ~ 23456789 | FALSE | TRUE |
| 4 | 12345678 ~ 01234567 ~ 12345678 ~ 23456789 | FALSE | FALSE |
| 5 | A0123456 ~ 12345678 ~ 01234567 ~ 12345678 ~ 23456789 | FALSE | TRUE |

But the right output should be this:

| ID | pattern | smaller7 | greater7 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 01234567 ~ 01234567 ~ 12345678 ~ 23456789 ~ A012345 | FALSE | FALSE |
| 2 | A012345 ~ 12345678 ~ A01234 ~ 12345678 ~ 23456789 ~ A012345 | TRUE | **FALSE** |
| 3 | A012345 ~ 12345678 ~ 01234567 ~ 12345678 ~ 23456789 | FALSE | **FALSE** |
| 4 | 12345678 ~ 01234567 ~ 12345678 ~ 23456789 | FALSE | FALSE |
| 5 | A0123456 ~ 12345678 ~ 01234567 ~ 12345678 ~ 23456789 | FALSE | TRUE |

Whats wrong with my grepl? I need a solution without splitting column. Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you are just missing a few brackets here and there. I also tried to be a bit more explicit with the digits.

```r
# less than 7 digits
test[, smaller7 := grepl("(^| )[[:alpha:]]+([[:alnum:]]{1,5})($| )", pattern),]
# more than 7 digits
test[, greater7 := grepl("(^| )[[:alpha:]]+([[:alnum:]]{7,})($| )", pattern),]
test
#   ID                                                     pattern smaller7 greater7
#1:  1         01234567 ~ 01234567 ~ 12345678 ~ 23456789 ~ A012345    FALSE    FALSE
#2:  2 A012345 ~ 12345678 ~ A01234 ~ 12345678 ~ 23456789 ~ A012345     TRUE    FALSE
#3:  3         A012345 ~ 12345678 ~ 01234567 ~ 12345678 ~ 23456789    FALSE    FALSE
#4:  4                   12345678 ~ 01234567 ~ 12345678 ~ 23456789    FALSE    FALSE
#5:  5        A0123456 ~ 12345678 ~ 01234567 ~ 12345678 ~ 23456789    FALSE     TRUE
```

Also here is the alternative with `[A-z]` and `[A-z0-9]`.

```r
# less than 7 digits
test[, smaller7 := grepl("(^| )[A-z]+([A-z0-9]{1,5})($| )", pattern),]
# more than 7 digits
test[, greater7 := grepl("(^| )[A-z]+([A-z0-9]{7,})($| )", pattern),]
```

But from your description what you probably want is `"(^| )[[:alpha:]]+([[:alnum:]]{1,6})($| )"` instead of `"(^| )[[:alpha:]]+([[:alnum:]]{1,5})($| )"` to really get something under 7 and on the other hand `{8,}`.
Otherwise you get also lengths which are exactly 7.

Comment: If I am using this `"(^| )[A-Z]+([[:digit:]]{1,6})($| )"` there is not the option, that the search string can contain another letter, for example the new pattern: `"V07AB3 ~ 1234567"`. The output in column `smaller7`is FALSE, but should be TRUE.

Comment: I edited the answer so that you can use `alnum` and also that the first part `[A-Z]` is fixed to length 1.

Comment: Thank you. So, `[[:alnum:]]` is the same as `[A-Z0-9]`? And is it really necessary to fix the first [A-Z] with `{1}`?

Comment: Yes it has the same effect. Also you are right and can leave out the one since it is implicit. In the end you basically had the right answer yourself except for the brackets.

Comment: I edited the answer to remove the mix of styles and remove the {1} to reduce the confusion.

Answer (score 1):

1. Within `data.table` expressions, don't use `test$` unless you *really know* that you need to reach back out to the pre-expression version. That sounds funny, I know. Just use the column name, it's faster/more-efficient.
2. We can use a word-boundary, perhaps a little clearer than `($| )` and such.

```r
test[, smaller7 := grepl("\\b[A-Z][0-9]{1,5}\\b", pattern)]
test[, greater7 := grepl("\\b[A-Z][0-9]{7,}\\b", pattern)]
#       ID                                 pattern smaller7 greater7
#    <int>                                  <char>   <lgcl>   <lgcl>
# 1:     1 01234567 ~ 01234567 ~ 12345678 ~ 234...    FALSE    FALSE
# 2:     2 A012345 ~ 12345678 ~ A01234 ~ 123456...     TRUE    FALSE
# 3:     3 A012345 ~ 12345678 ~ 01234567 ~ 1234...    FALSE    FALSE
# 4:     4 12345678 ~ 01234567 ~ 12345678 ~ 234...    FALSE    FALSE
# 5:     5 A0123456 ~ 12345678 ~ 01234567 ~ 123...    FALSE     TRUE
```